`extern inline` vs `static inline` shared functions. What is the correct form?
There are two possible ways to define shared inline functions:
1st form, extern inline
main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "file1.h"

extern inline int f(int x);

int main() {
    printf("Hello inline function: %d\n", f(1));

    int y = some_function();

    printf("Hi from file1: %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}

main.h:
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

extern inline int f(int x) {
    return x;
}

#endif // MAIN_H

file1.c:
#include "main.h"
#include "file1.h"

// Use the extern inline function in another file
int some_function() {
    return f(3);
}

file.h:
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

// Declare the some_function function
int some_function();

#endif // FILE1_H

2nd form, static inline
Keep file.c and file.h unchanged.
main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "file1.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello inline function: %d\n", f(1));

    int y = some_function();

    printf("Hi from file1: %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}

main.h:
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

static inline int f(int x) {
    return x;
}

#endif // MAIN_H


Both approaches work:
❯ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c main.c -o main.o
gcc file1.o main.o -o main
❯ ./main
Hello inline function: 1
Hi from file1: 3

Which is the correct form?
I've searched for this answer, but there is no duplicate post about it.

extern inline int f(int x); in main.c (1st form) is superflous, because you get it via the #included main.h.

In general I don't see the point in adding extern to an inline function. extern means the implementation is in another translation unit, which contradicts inlining.

@wohlstad No, it is not. If I remove this line I get an error: main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `f'; file1.o:file1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here

This is because you put the implementation in a header file (which is #included in more than one file), without declaring it static.

@wohlstad "I don't see the point in adding extern to an inline function. extern means the implementation is in another translation unit, which contradicts inlining." So please, tell me, which is the correct way to define inline functions to be used across multiple source files.

I would go with the 2nd version. But I admit I am not a C expert. Lets see what others have to say about it.

The static inline version is not an approach that I've used, but appears correct in your post. I believe its advantage is that is seems to be the simplest one to get right and maintain. Its disadvantage is that each translation unit that requires a non-inlined copy of the function gets its own such copy. So the program could end up containing multiple copies of the function - one for each t.u. where the function's address is taken or the compiler opts to not inline the function at least once.

The approach that I've used differs from your first in that I did not use the extern specifier along with inline in the function definition in the header file. This approach requires an extern declaration of the function (as you have in main.c) in exactly one translation unit to provide 1 copy for use when the function is not inlined. (This should be verified, as it has been awhile since I've done this.) However, gcc will have issues with this if you don't specify standard C and the IBM compiler may also have issues here. See this post

See also this It shows an example of the unadorned inline in the header with an extern inline in one translation unit. The first version in the post I believe to be incorrect and has the potential to result in link time errors due to generation of multiple extern definitions for the function.

IMO, you should always use the static inline function definition in the header.  The rules for such functions are relatively simple.  The rules for inline functions without static (with and without extern) are more complex.
The C standard defines the inline type specifier in §6.7.4 Function specifiers, but it makes fairly inscrutable reading.  The C99 Rationale discusses inline in §6.7.4.
There are numerous relevant questions and answers on Stack Overflow, including:

Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99?
inline, static, extern in C99
What's the difference between static inline, extern inline, and a normal inline function?
static inline functions in a header file
Clarification over internal linkage of inline functions in C — which illustrates some of the issues with using inline functions not qualified as static inline.

